# Difference between /Home and /home?

Tags: filesystem

Total Ubuntu/Linux in general noob here.

What is the difference between `/home` and `/Home` ? I've noticed I need to use sudo to do anything in `/home`. `/Home` (home folder?) has pictures, videos, etc. in it so thats where I want to really create new folders and stuff but I can't seem to get to it using cd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `/Home` you are probably referring to what in Nautilus is signified with 'Home'. The name of this folder actually is not "Home". This folder is named /home/ in the filesystem. `/home` is the folder which contains all the users Home-folders. (Which explains why you need `sudo` to do anything there.) `/home/username` is the personal folder of that user.

So, you can type `cd /home/` and press tab to see which options you have (or if you're the only user it will autocomplete your username). `ls /home` will list all the files and folders in `/home`. If you have anything there, I would highly recommend moving it to your personal folder, since that's much cleaner.

Faster ways you can cd back to it, are `cd` (without arguments) or `cd ~` (with a possible path behind it, like ~/Pictures )

Comment: Ah ok, thanks, I think the reason I couldn't cd to what I am calling /Home is because I am already in it when I turn terminal on. If I do ls it lists pictures, music, etc. I am not sure how to get back to it once I cd to another folder though

Comment: I've added a little bit about how you can quickly cd back to it. I hope it's useful :)