# Missing Downloads directory

Tags: java, eclipse

I am using ubuntu 12.04. I tried to install Eclipse so I followed some steps from a website in that they have mentioned the following steps:

```
sudo su
chown -R root:root /home/downloads/eclipse && mv /home/downloads/eclipse /opt 
ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin/eclipse
```

To execute eclipse use

```
eclipse
```

But it showed me as eclipse not installed and it showed me to install it. When I tried to install it I had net problem so it didn't install. After that I found that Downloads directory was lost.

Comment: `/home/downloads`? I doubt that "downloads" is your user name... When "home directory" is mentioned anywhere, it ususally means `/home/username`.

Comment: Can you please post the output of your failed installation and a link to the guidelines you followed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`/home/downloads` is the home directory of the user downloads. `/home/$USER/Downloads` is the downloads folder of your user.

You can find more information here:
[Difference between /Home and /home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/104496/difference-between-home-and-home)

Comment: No need for that bit I removed. $USER will be changed to the user name ;)

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realize this is a real variable :)